# "Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent" error occurs after solving "Connection timeout" error

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-php-sdk

In my app, CURL was timing out and thus resulting the error:

```
CurlException: 28: Connection time-out
```

So, I increased the `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` value in `base_facebook.php` from `10` to `30`. After that, the `Connection time-out` error just vanished but came the new one:

```
Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent
```

The line it indicates the error is at 49 in `facebook.php` file where the code `session_start();` is there.

When I changed the CURL timeout value back to 10 or 15, this session cache error goes off. But the timeout error is back!

I am using the latest PHP SDK (which was last updated two days ago).

The following is the present CURL options in `base_facebook.php`:

```
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,
CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'facebook-php-3.2',
```

Any ideas/suggestions on how to clear this issue?

Comment: Did you manage to sort it out? If not, let us know what's happening

Comment: I tried with tweaking the values. After changing the `CONNECTTIMEOUT` value to `30` and `TIMEOUT` value to `120`, seems to be working. But I am keeping it under observation!

Comment: How long does it take to execute? Did you try executing the same query using curl from command line? Does it take equally long?

Comment: Less than a minute. No I didn't tried it via CURL. Let me see if it is working as I am constantly observing it's performance. FB's updations are making me crazy now a days. :P Another issue was with shared sessions. And I have tweaked a bit and it is also under observation now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your files are saved without the BOM encoding, especially the one which gives you the `headers already sent` error.

I've had this problem before - even though I was not outputting anything, there were extra characters in the file.

Comment: Thanks. But my PHP files contains unicode characters. So encoded with `utf-8`. And I have checked before and after the PHP tags for any extra spaces or characters. But there wasn't any.

Comment: You won't see the BOM in your editor :) You need to save your files using utf-8 without BOM encoding. You can usually set it in preferences of your file/project or when you are saving the file.

Comment: hmmm... I should check that now. I am using Notepad++ for local development. Then after uploading to server, I use the web file manager and do the modifications(opened in utf8). I will look into BOM now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

**headers already sent** error usualy occurs when you use php redirect. If you use php redirect use javascript redirect instead of.

Comment: Thanks. I am already using the JS way to redirect to the login page. I mean, outputting the JS code from PHP, just like the FB doc recommends for iframe apps. Because sending redirect header from PHP, to iFrame apps won't work.